# Prove $n \choose m$ is divisible by n when $\gcd(m,n)=1$

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients

I know that $p \choose k$ is divisible by $p$ for all $k \in \{1, 2, \ldots,p-1\}$. But I am trying to work on a generalization as in the title but do not know how to prove it.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Consider the fact that $\binom{n-1}{m-1}$ is an integer, and $\binom nm$ is $\frac nm$ times larger.